# Python Redis отследить окончание срока годности ключа

Tags: python, redis

Использую Redis по следующему шаблону:

1. При первом обращении пользователя к приложению данные из MongoDB (инвентарь, статистика и многое другое) попадает в ОЗУ (Redis) и живут там 10 минут.
2. Далее пользователь может использовать, изменять эти данные
3. После того, как пользователь закончил, новые данные остаются в ОЗУ и пропадут через некоторое время.

Собственно загвоздка в том, что я не хочу чтобы эти данные просто пропадали, а отправлялись в БД, так как больше ненужны в текущий момент пользователю. Могу ли я как-то отследить этот момент, чтобы сохранить свежее данные в внешнюю базу данных?

Должен ли я делать какой-то вечный цикл, который проверяет срок годности данных и в случае, если они залежались и не используются, отправлять их в БД? Или для этого  есть какой-то встроенный инструмент в Redis?

Comment: поставь в планировщик запись из редиса в базу. пока юзер полдьзуется данными передвигай этот таймер

Comment: Это популярная практика? А если одновременно будет 10к юзеров, то в redis уйдет 10к записей, это не станет проблемой?

Comment: популярная практика записывать в базу каждое изменение с отсрочкой на "после завершения запроса"

Comment: кхм, я опечатался. Я хотел написать, что в планировщик Redis уйдет сразу 10к задач, не станет ли это проблемой? Может все таки лучше использовать для этого подобие вечного цикла (по аналогии с 1 задачей), который бы проверял "востребованность" данных и в случае их невостребованности уже складывал в "медленную" базу данных?

Comment: Да, это может быть проблемой, потому чаще делают copy-on-wtite и редис по сути ускоряет только чтение горячих данных и снимает блокировку на "дождаться записи". Вечный цикл создась нагрузку по процессору на проверку каждой записи. Планировщик нагрузит память. CoW нагрузит диск - выбирайте чем жертвовать - золотой середины нет

Comment: У меня вырисовалась следующая идея, а именно:
1. Вместо вечного грубого решения с вечным циклом поставить 1 задачу в редис, которая будет совершать цикл раз в час
2. Получать нужные мне данные (которые более невостребованны юзером) с помощью ZRANGE и unix-time
3. Полученные данные сохранять в медленную бд и удалять из redis
Правильный ли такой подход?

Comment: правильный подход "CoW" остальное оптимизации и компромисы. Требуется ли вашему серверу оптимизация на данном этапе?

Comment: Можно пример CoW с использованием redis?

Answer (score 0):

Если не брать во внимание вашу терминологию (Redis != RAM и даже Redis !== RAM) то идея про "вечный цикл" разбиваеться о мысль - "а вдруг в этот самый момент, когда там все залежались, другой источник изменит данные этого пользователя ? " . Нууу.. например ... админ. Ну вот админ взял и поменял данные пользователя, которые хранятся где то локально, а потом эти данные затирают внесенные админом данные ??

А вот смотрите, еще вариант - пользователь внес миллион данных и пошел спать, а в это время выключили свет и эти данные канули в лету ? Что вам скажет пользователь ? Ну, возможно расскажет про то что нужно вечный цикл как то делать более цикличным ?

А вот еще вариант - вы сделали вечный цикл и научились определять когда "пора записывать данные". И вот приложение пытается записать, а в это время рвется соединение. И рвется на время больше чем таймаут условной записи условной библиотеки ? И что делать ? Вы для этого внедрите ИИ чтоб он определял осуществилась ли запись ? Уверен что то отличный вариант для решаемой задачи, однако похоже что я вас пытаюсь убедить что данная задача решается не так.

Comment: А почему вы подумали, что я считаю Redis != RAM? Наоборот. Конечно, возможно эта задача не решается таким способом, но как иначе? Мне казалось многие так и делают, во многих проектах ведь часто такое бывает, что из-за резко упавшего сервера происходит небольшой "откат назад".

Comment: Как то Вы все радикально все отвергаете. Дайте человеку попробовать. Конечно, Ваш опыт ценен. А негативный опыт темболее. Но что если он сможет в итоге решить те проблемы которые Вы описали? А с таким подходом как Вы обрисовали, он даже пробовать перестанет, так как будет боятся ветра который замкнет провода линии электропередачи питающей сервер.

Comment: Ответ поднимает интересные темы, но, в сущности, на вопрос не отвечает =/

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica несомненно вопрос выстрела себе в ногу описан в классике, однако должен ли быть ответ с подробным порядком действий ?

Comment: @V.March я ровно из тех людей которые не на ходят ничего хорошего в хождении по граблям и исходя из своего же опыта не нахожу ничего интересного в том чтобы "попробовать неправильно" (возможно стоит написать раздельно, я не знаю). 

Почему вы считаете что теорему косинусов вы должны доказать самостоятельно, а не попросту изучить чужой опыт ?  Разве здесь есть разница ?

Comment: @zalex Так почему не показать ему где грабли лежат и как их обходить? Может Вы смогли до 10-х граблей дойти, а он сможет до 20-х. А другой придумает "граблеход" и преодолеет этот сложный участок. Так как изучит эти грабли и будет знать их "в лицо". Все фичи рождаются в процессе создания какого-то костыля когда функционала нужного нет "из коробки". Потому я и сказал что Ваш отрицательный опыт ценен, и ценен как раз для того чтобы сделать выводы с чем можно столкнуться, что нужно учитывать. Он даже более ценен чем готовое решение если написать Ваши рекомендации менее радикально и фаталистично.